# In React Hooks, when calling setState directly during render, is the re-render guaranteed to run before the render of children?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In React Hooks, we can call the `setState()` of a React state hook directly inside a functional component. This is described in the official React docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-do-i-implement-getderivedstatefromprops).

According to the docs:

> [Y]ou can update the state right during rendering. React will re-run the component with updated state immediately after exiting the first render.

What is unclear to me though is whether "first render" means the first render of the **whole component tree**, or just the first render of the component that called the `setState()`? Furthermore, what happens to effects that are scheduled during that render? Are they executed, or discarded?

This distinction is important to my use case because I'm calling `setState()` inside the rendering function to keep state in sync with props as described by Dan Abramov [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15523#issuecomment-553204248). In my use case, the state which is synced to the prop, and the original prop, are passed down to a child. I want to be able to rely on the fact that the prop and state are in sync in the children, which will not be the case if the parent re-renders only after the whole component tree has rendered.

**MY TESTS**

I have tested this, and it seems like the `setState()` re-renders the component immediately before any child component is rendered and any effects scheduled during the initial render are discarded. This is the behavior I want. I don't know however what the specification is. Can I rely on this behavior in all cases?

**THE CODE**

Here is some code to illustrate this concretely:

```
function Foo({x}) {
    const [xPlus1, setXPlus1] = React.useState(x + 1)
    if (xPlus1 !== x + 1) setXPlus1(x + 1)
    useEffect(()=>{
        // Am I guaranteed that this will never throw?
        if (xPlus1 !== x + 1) throw new Error()
    })
    return <Bar x={x} xPlus1={xPlus1} />
}

function Bar({x, xPlus1}) {
    // Am I guaranteed that this will never throw?
    if (xPlus1 !== x + 1) throw new Error()
    return <p> {x} + 1 = {xPlus1} </p>
}
```